# Is section logging in krb5.conf works on the kerberos client?

Tags: kerberos, mitkerberos

Client /etc/krb5.conf:

```
...
[logging] 
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log 
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log 
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
...
```

Kerberos client worked, but log files are empty...
write permissions on files granted to all.

Comment: Can you try in /tmp just to be sure ?